# Building Tesseract 5.3.3 with leptonica 1.84.1 on RedHat gives undefined reference errors at Make step

Tags: tesseract, leptonica, redhat-containers

**Problem:** When trying to setup tesseract after installing leponica (please see the steps to reproduce section below) I get following error message at "make" command run.

```
  CXXLD    tesseract
/usr/bin/ld: src/tesseract-tesseract.o: in function `main':
tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0xdd): undefined reference to `setMsgSeverity'
/usr/bin/ld: tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0x296): undefined reference to `getLeptonicaVersion'
/usr/bin/ld: tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2b7): undefined reference to `lept_free'
/usr/bin/ld: tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2bc): undefined reference to `getImagelibVersions'
/usr/bin/ld: tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2dd): undefined reference to `lept_free'
/usr/bin/ld: tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0x966): undefined reference to `setMsgSeverity'
/usr/bin/ld: tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0x143e): undefined reference to `pixRead'
/usr/bin/ld: tesseract.cpp:(.text.startup+0x14d7): undefined reference to `pixDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxaCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `l_generateCIDataForPdf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixWriteMem'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxaGetBox'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixAnd'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRotateOrth'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetXRes'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixReadTiff'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixReadMem'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRenderPolyline'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixInvert'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixClipBoxToForeground'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaAddBox'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSubtract'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetYRes'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetAllArbitrary'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `ptaDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixConnComp'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaGetPix'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixReadMemTiff'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetHeight'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaDisplayTiledInColumns'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixOr'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `ptaAddPt'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `l_CIDataDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaAddPix'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixReduceRankBinaryCascade'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetData'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `numaDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixReadFromMultipageTiff'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixCopy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixConvertTo8'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixForegroundFraction'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGenerateCIData'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRotate180'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxaDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixCountConnComp'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetDimensions'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixClipRectangle'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixConvertTo32'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixDilateBrick'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetOrClearBorder'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxaReplaceBox'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxaAddBox'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaGetCount'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixClone'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetSpp'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixCreateTemplate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixReadMemFromMultipageTiff'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetAll'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxaGetBoxGeometry'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetYRes'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRasterop'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixCountPixels'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxaGetCount'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetText'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `numaGetCount'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixExpandReplicate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRenderBoxArb'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `bmfCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaGetBox'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetInRect'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetDepth'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixClearInRect'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetPixel'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaClear'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSauvolaBinarizeTiled'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixCountPixelsByRow'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetInputFormat'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixCloseBrick'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaConvertToPdf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixOpenBrick'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxGetGeometry'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetMasked'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `l_getFormattedDate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetWpl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRemoveColormap'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixBlockconv'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `composeRGBPixel'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixWrite'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetWidth'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixErodeBrick'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixZero'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `boxSetGeometry'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRenderPolylineArb'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixaReplacePix'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `bmfDestroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixDistanceFunction'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetColormap'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixRemoveAlpha'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGenerateHalftoneMask'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `findFileFormat'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `zlibCompress'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixGetXRes'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixScale'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetPixel'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `numaGetIValue'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSeedfillBinary'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `ptaCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixConvert24To32'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixAddSingleTextblock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `findFileFormatBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `pixSetSpp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4481: tesseract] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/tesseract/tesseract-5.3.3'
make: *** [Makefile:8199: all-recursive] Error 1
```

**Reference material used to troubleshoot this issue**
http://www.leptonica.org/source/README.html

https://github.com/cesco345/OpenCV-With-the-ODROID-XU4Q/blob/master/opencv_installation.txt

**Steps to reproduce**

- Just as a summary, I am trying to create this environment using docker container on my windows laptop using WSL.
- I have tried both redhat and ubuntu docker images and both give similar error as above.
- Various documentations and installation steps found online are for older versions of leptonica and not much of help.
- I have tried to compile setup steps from different online tutorials or sources so not too sure about what exactly all of them do.

**Command to run docker container**

```
docker container run  -v /mnt/d/:/mnt -it --rm redhat/ubi9:latest
```

**Installing required packages inside container once started**

```
yum install gcc-c++
yum install -y libtool autoconf automake libpng-devel libtiff-devel libwebp-devel openjpeg2 libjpeg-devel libjpeg-turbo giflib zlib-devel libarchive libcurl-devel
yum install sudo
sudo dnf install wget
sudo yum install zip unzip
yum install autoconf-archive
wget https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/releases/download/1.84.1/leptonica-1.84.1.tar.gz
mv leptonica-1.84.1.tar.gz ./opt/tesseract
gunzip leptonica-1.84.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf leptonica-1.84.1.tar
cd leptonica-1.84.1
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
make -j4 check


cd /opt/tesseract/
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/refs/tags/5.3.3.tar.gz
gunzip 5.3.3.tar.gz 
tar -xvf 5.3.3.tar 
rm 5.3.3.tar
cd tesseract-5.3.3/
export LEPTONICA_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/leptonica"
export LEPTONICA_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib/"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/leptonica -lpng -ljpeg -lz"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"
export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR="/usr/include/leptonica"
./autogen.sh
LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include/leptonica ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib
make
sudo make install (yet to be done since the make step is where its failing)
```

Comment: I do not use docker, but I doubt about quality of posted command: why do you use gunzip? You can do gz decompression with tar.  Why you set all that env variables? /usr/local/ is standard installation place and ./configure take cares about that.